# AWS SAM CLI times out

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli

I am creating a handler in AWS lambda that returns a file for my Single Page Application(SPA). The function runs fast (couple of ms).But still I have to run it multiple times, almost simultaneously, and then they timeout. My timeout is 60 seconds. I think that has something to do with docker but I am not so sure. Is there something I can do?

Here is my code:`pastebin.com/TdqAu3Gx`! Even with other functions it takes mush more time to get the response, compared to the execution time.

## EDIT:

After some time I published the front-end on Netlify. But after making some functions I encountered the same bug. The fowoling code works in aws sam local.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

type MyReq struct {
    Username string `json:"username"`
}

func handler(m events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    // log.Println(m.Username)

    fmt.Println("\n\n", m.Body, "\n\n")
    return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{
        Body: m.Body,
    }, nil
}
func main() {
    lambda.Start(handler)
}
```

But does not work in the real was lambda. (It works but I get the full json as text for exaple headers are not set on response, but i can see them as text in the body). If I change `events.APIGatewayProxyResponse` and `events.APIGatewayProxyRequest` to `MyRequest` and a string respectively it works in lambda but timeouts in sam local. In my `template.json` under `Resources` I have :

```
"TestFunction": {
        "Type": "AWS::Serverless::Function",
        "Properties": {
            "CodeUri": "MY_BUCKET",
            "Handler": "testf",
            "Role": "My Lambda role",
            "Events": {
                "RegisterEvent": {
                    "Type": "Api",
                    "Properties": {
                        "Path": "/testf",
                        "Method": "POST"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I make the code work both on AWS Lambda and SAM Local? If someone has a working template of a sam app that works both on SAM and AWS and can open source it, I would be very thankful.

Comment: can you share the code and explain your use case with more details ?

Comment: Yes, I added a pastebin link since the code is too mush.

Comment: `still I have to run it multiple times, almost simultaneously` - these can cause `cold start` for new containers   https://medium.com/thundra/dealing-with-cold-starts-in-aws-lambda-a5e3aa8f532

Comment: @DmitryHarnitski The function is actually executed (yes with small delay), but it is not sent properly. Sometimes everything is OK but with larger payloads it takes much time and times out. Is there a configuration of the throughput? And thank you for the information about the cold start. Much appreciated.

Comment: it is hard to say because you have too many moving parts in your project. but try this -  1) check if you close all resources after use 2) Increase allocated ram and cpu for your lambda

Comment: allocating more ram, thus more CPU power, doesn't affect it. And I am not so sure what "close all resources" means. Does it mean something like ```defer file.Close()``` or something about docker.